# Viewing image from sql table

Tags: android, mysql, sql-server, bitmap, android-sqlite

hi iam currently working on an android app that stores images to database and it retrieves it back for image view.I convert the image to bit amp and upload it to mysql table
my code is 
following code to fetch image from ImageGallery:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
           android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
     startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

It will start ImageGallery, now you can select an image, and in onActivityResult you can decode the image into bitmap, as explained in the link: here:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent     imageReturnedIntent) { 
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

   switch(requestCode) { 
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null,   null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
     }
    }
  }
```

the php code to upload bitmap
to server :

```
  $base= $_REQUEST['yourselectedimage'];
  $buffer = mysql_real_escape_string($base);
```

then inserting the $buffer to table blob column type
but i don't know how to display the image bit map from table to an image view,please help me in that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OnActivityresult method, add this code sample.

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
```

Method would look like ...

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null,   null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
     }
```